# Can't access member data Three.js TypeScript

Tags: javascript, three.js, typescript

I'm using three.d.ts from DefinitelyTyped and TypeScript. I have the following code

```
class WoodStyle extends THREE.MeshBasicMaterial{
    putTexture(image: any){
        super.map=image;
    }
    constructor(){
        LoadImage().then(putTexture);
        super();
    }
}
```

In which I load an image and then I update the material with the new image. But when I'm trying to compile the code it shows an error: `2340 Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if you're extending `MeshBasicMaterial`, wouldn't `map` be a property of you rew class? so case you could `this.map...`, no? not a typescript user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing an inherited property, use `this`:

```
class WoodStyle extends THREE.MeshBasicMaterial{
    putTexture(image: any){
        this.map=image;
    }
    constructor(){
        LoadImage().then(putTexture);
        super();
    }
}
```